# Does stellar takes fee for resolving a federated address?

Tags: transactions, accounts, federation, fees

I did a transaction from my one of my stellar accounts to my federated stellar address which is under another account. But while sending I made the mistake of not giving the complete federated address and hence this address couldn't be resolved and transaction failed!

The interesting thing is XLM was withdrawn from my account which didn't get credited to my federated address supported account  and a fee of 100 stroops was also taken.

So does stellar takes fee for resolving a federated address?

Comment: What wallet are you using? if transaction failed it shouldn't have charged you

Comment: I'm using lobstr. Even though they might not have charged me how could I loose the xlm i send when i gave an incomplete federation address? @umbrel

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not take any fees, it's just tool to resolve stellar addresses and return relative public key, and it does not connect with Stellar network

Comment: Thanks man! But could you tell me  how i lost xlm i send when i gave an incomplete federation address?

Comment: the stellar take fees even if the transaction failed

Comment: Why does stellar take fee for that?

Comment: I think because you use their network